# Algorithm for finding the v=1 state of an H2O molecule

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-modeling, quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, vibrations

In the context of simulating the dissociation dynamics of an H₂O molecule on a metal surface, what algorithm is employed for generating the initial state of a tri-atomic non-linear molecule, such as H₂O, in the **first vibrational excited state (v=1)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "what algorithm is employed for generating the initial state of a tri-atomic non-linear molecule, such as H₂O, in the first vibrational excited state (v=1)?"

To get the v=1 state (wavefunction) of a trinuclear and non-linear molecule, you can start by building a potential energy surface for the molecule. This can be done using [quantum-chemistry](/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) [software](/questions/tagged/software) for doing [electronic-structure](/questions/tagged/electronic-structure) calculations, for example [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) ones include [open-molcas](/questions/tagged/open-molcas), [pyscf](/questions/tagged/pyscf), [psi4](/questions/tagged/psi4), etc., and proprietary ones include [gaussian](/questions/tagged/gaussian), [orc](/questions/tagged/orc),[q-chem](/questions/tagged/q-chem),etc.

Once you have a potential energy surface, you now need to solve the vibrational Schroedinger equation for the molecule. For dinuclear molecules, LEVEL (which is open-source and available on its own, and also available within [open-molcas](/questions/tagged/open-molcas)) is the most popular, but for trianuclear molecules  you can use the [TROVE software](https://github.com/Trovemaster/TROVE).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't exactly need the wavefunction for v=1 state rather I want the geometry (atomic positions) of the H2O molecule in v=1 state. How are initial configurations (for AIMD simulations) generated for excited energetic states? I have some idea about how it's done for diatoms (Morse' anharmonic potential can be used to find the bond distance). But what to do for non-linear triatomic molecule?

Comment: You asked for the "state", and in this context the most likely (or only) meaning is "wavefunction". If you want to know how to get a "geometry",  I recommend to post a new question.